# Microsoft Power BI on iOS

Tags: ios, web-analytics

I want to implement 'Microsoft Power BI' on my iOS application.  How to integrate it on iOS application? Is there any SDK available?

Comment: do you mean of visualizing the output in your iOS application?

Comment: The same way we use google anyalytics

Answer (score 0):

You can read this - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-mobile-ipad-app-get-started/

Available in App Store - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-power-bi/id929738808

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I know iOS application of power bi is available. I want to integrate it on my iOS application.

Comment: if that's the case, I believe a lot of ways to do it, depends on your situation. you can try to create embedded view here - https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-publish-to-web/ or you can even do a customize web application to retrieve data and connect to your iOS app